# How to separate a tuple inside a list?

Tags: python, sql, list, tuples

Im working an a project using Tkinter right now. Whenever I input 'Japan', it prints out:

```
[('Japan', '23,473', 0.0, 985.0, '3,392', '19,096')]
```

I'm not really sure if that's a list or if it's a tuple? I want to seperate all of that data thats seperated by the commas into different variables. Heres what I have so far. If you see any other holes in my code help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

```
def subby():
        answer=country_name.get()
        l_answer = answer.capitalize()
        sql_command = "SELECT * FROM covid WHERE `name` = ?;"
        values = (l_answer,)
        cursor.execute(sql_command,values)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print (data)
        users0.set(data[0])
        users1.set(data[1])
        users2.set(data[2])
        users3.set(data[3])
        users4.set(data[4])
        users5.set(data[5])
```

Comment: You should access like `data[0][0]`, `data[0][1]`, because it's a list that contains a tuple, so `data[0]` will be `('Japan', '23,473', 0.0, 985.0, '3,392', '19,096')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have right there is a list inside of which there is a tuple, so as to access the first element of the list u can say `data[0]` and now you have

```
('Japan', '23,473', 0.0, 985.0, '3,392', '19,096')
```

this is a tuple.

And you can access items inside tuple by saying `data[0][0]` which is `'Japan'` or `data[0][1]` which is `'23,473'` and so on. Hope it cleared you're doubt, lemme know if any errors or doubts :D

Answer (score 0):

Its a list of tuples. As per [Mysql Python Connector Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html),

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a list of tuples. If no more rows are available, it returns an empty list.

If you're querying with the fixed columns, use `namedtuple` which will help for better code readability and use.

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple                                                                                                                                   

In [2]: result_set = namedtuple("ResultSet", ["column1", "column2", "column3"])                                                                                              

In [3]: result_set('Japan', '23,473', 0.0)                                                                                                                                  
Out[3]: ResultSet(column1='Japan', column2='23,473', column3=0.0)

In [4]: rs = result_set('Japan', '23,473', 0.0)                                                                                                                             

In [5]: rs.column1                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: 'Japan'
```